# Extending User class with uniqueness and Non-Null

Tags: django

I extended by User class through AbstractUser to:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    Primary_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    Primary_address_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
```

An email and password is the only requirement to create a new user.

1) How do you make the email a unique field? I want to avoid adding a new column by adding this to CustomUser (or is this the right thing to do?):

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

2) Since username is no longer used, how does one allow NULL value for username field?  Is it better to keep it NULL or put the email address in username field too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add null in the username

```
username = models.Charfield(default= None, null=True)
```

and your code to constrain unique emails is correct

```
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

Comment: If I set username NULL = True, I get the following error:  django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'username' in class 'CustomUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'

Comment: You should be extending from AbstractBaseUser and not AbstractUser

Comment: AbstractBaseUser create a new user class, no? I just want to inherit from the existing User class.

Comment: Sorr, I got the question wrong. What do you want do achieve, could you elaboraate?

Comment: I want to add extra fields to the existing User class, like above.  One change is the user only needs an email and password to create a new user.  I believe the default User class requires a username and password.  I want to make the user.email unique and to allow for NULL value for username.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that without creating a new user model